# Printing data from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to loop through this array, coming from a database and outputting the `Field_Name` and `Field_Value` to a webpage.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field_Name] => First Name
            [Field_Value] => søren
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field_Name] => Last Name
            [Field_Value] => hansen
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field_Name] => Email
            [Field_Value] => s.hansen@hansens.dk
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field_Name] => medlem
            [Field_Value] => ja
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field_Name] => Profilbillede
            [Field_Value] => sCZ
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field_Name] => bestyrelse
            [Field_Value] => nej
        )

)
```

If i use:

```
$count=0;
while ($count < 6) {
    $newdata = $data[$count];
    foreach ($newdata as $key => $val) {
        echo "<div class='list'>" . $key . " = " . $val . "</div><br><br>";
    }
$count++;
}
```

I get:

```
Field_Name = First Name



Field_Value = søren



Field_Name = Last Name



Field_Value = hansen
```

and so on....

But I need to get rid of `Field_Name` and `Field_Value` so the array will look like:

```
First Name: Søren

Last Name: Hansen
```

I've tried by using `$data[0]["Field_name"]`, but it's not working.  I'm going crazy now, so I need a push in the right direction.

I hope I have made it clear what I need to do.

Comment: So, if I understand well, you want to build a new "classical" associative array? or you only want to display specific informations from your original array?

Comment: How are you creating your array to begin with?

Comment: The array comes from the database. (im quite novice here so i hope that was what you meant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like..

```
//assuming you have data stored in $data..
$newdata = array();
foreach ($data as $object){

    if ($object->Field_Name && $object->Field_Value){

       $newData[$object->Field_Name] = $object->Field_Value;

    }      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The secondary dimensions are not arrays, they are objects! so you can't access them like that.

In short you should be able to do something like $data[0]->Field_name
or convert them to arrays then $data[0]["Field_name"], would work!

Comment: One other thing...Im not sure how your getting this data from a db, but if your using mysqli, you can use the fetch_assoc() function so that its always passed back as arrays so you can do $data[0]["Field_name"]

Comment: Aha!! That makes sence... it is coming from the $wpdb->get_results(); built in to wordpress so im not sure what it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach for this:

```
$count=0;
while ($count < 6) {
    $newdata = $data[$count];
    echo "<div class='list'>" . $newdata["Field_Name"] . " = " . $newdata["Field_Value"] . "</div>   <br><br>";
    $count++;
}
```